# Save a file using a model and non-model-based Form in Django

Tags: django, upload, filefield

I have a model with a FileField and a form that has a FileField as well. The form is not a ModelForm based on the model but it's a regular Form.

How do I save the uploaded file from the form to the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is what I was looking for:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
def save_file(request):
    mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
    file_content = ContentFile(request.FILES['video'].read())
    mymodel.video.save(request.FILES['video'].name, file_content)
```

Found a good explanation [here](http://www.nitinh.com/2009/02/django-example-filefield-and-imagefield/).

Answer (score 1):

If your model is

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

you can simply do

```
thing = Thing()
thing.document = request.FILES['Filedata']
thing.save()
```